# VBA | Word - How to get the value out of an InLine ScrollBar or how to have a similar ValueSlider?

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

I would like to add slidebars to my Word document.
To be able to ask from readers, how much they agree with a question from 0-100.
In excel i know how to handle such ActiveX controls, but in Word I could not figure sofar how to make it work.
Le say, if I have a ScrollBar placed InLie, named in Properties window: MyBar1.
How can I get its value via VBA?

I'm also open towards totally different approaches, I just need to feed such 0-100 scroll feedback from Word to my ExcelSheet.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be quite simple.
I don't know why `ActiveDocument.InLineShapes("SB_Q1_B131").value` did not work, but:
`ActiveDocument.SB_Q1_B131.value` Does work!

Comment: For the first to work, you'd need the InlineShape.OLEFormat.Object property to drill down to the underlying ActiveX object. The second communicates directly with the ActiveX, as a member of the `Document` properties (what you see in the VBA Editor's Properties window when you look at it in Design mode). Usually, I'd use `ThisDocument` rather than `ActiveDocument` - as I recall, you can't address such a control via this approach when your macro is hosted in another document. (I could be wrong, though - it's been a while since I played with this.)